# Object refrence not set to an intance of an object

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have one dropdownlist  of column intrestedFields,i have added ListItem attributes on that dropdownlist

now problems are when i put that intrest_field() method in postback , ListItem attributes are not showing ,
and when i put it outside of postback , listitem attributes are showing but my another dropdownlist items are not showing and also showing error " Object refrence not set to an intance of an object ".

i have tried with PreRender but same problem occurs.

.cs code

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        intrest_field();
    }

 public void intrest_field()

{

    ListItem l1 = new ListItem();
    l1 = drpfield.Items.FindByValue("1");
    l1.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;font-weight:bold;font-size:larger");
    l1.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    l1.Value = "-1";

    ListItem l2 = drpfield.Items.FindByValue("2");
    l2.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;font-weight:bold;font-size:larger");
    l2.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    l2.Value = "-1";

    ListItem l3 = drpfield.Items.FindByValue("3");
    l3.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;font-weight:bold;font-size:larger");
    l3.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    l3.Value = "-1";


}
```

.aspx code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpfield" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="190px" 
                    AutoPostBack="True">

                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Top Categories</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem >Accounts</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Financial </asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>ITES</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">HR</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Marketing</asp:ListItem>    </asp:DropDownList>
```

after this l1.attributes.add style losts,
when i put intrest_field() in

```
protected void drpfield_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

it works but my another dropdownlist item are not showing

i.e after selecting item from drpfield,when i select items from my another dropdownlist country than it is not showing state.
without using dropdownlist drpfield it works

what could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong way. For example, You are finding item by value "1", changing to "-1" and after postback you are trying to find the item by Value "1", which doesn't exist anymore!

```
l1 = drpfield.Items.FindByValue("1");
... ... ...
l1.Value = "-1";
```

I would suggest not to change value to -1:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    intrest_field();
}

public void intrest_field()
{

    ListItem l1 = new ListItem();
    l1 = drpfield.Items.FindByValue("1");
    l1.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;font-weight:bold;font-size:larger");
    l1.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    //l1.Value = "-1";

    ListItem l2 = drpfield.Items.FindByValue("2");
    l2.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;font-weight:bold;font-size:larger");
    l2.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    //l2.Value = "-1";

    ListItem l3 = drpfield.Items.FindByValue("3");
    l3.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;font-weight:bold;font-size:larger");
    l3.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    //l3.Value = "-1";
}
```

And if there's a reason to set the value to -1, there should be way to do it in other way.

If you keep `l1.Value = "-1",you can check if l1 is null of course, but after postback it will be null and attributes will not be applied.